# When using pdo's data binding,is there a way to get the actual sql executed by MySQL?

Tags: mysql, data-binding

The SQL in program is like :

```
select * from table where column=?
```

But the actual sql should have no `?`,I need this in a statistics functionality.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but there isn't any such thing like "acutal SQL". The PDO binding translates into an SQL *prepared statement*, which also looks like you code, directly in the database: `PREPARE ... FROM SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = ?`.

Binding the parameters to variables is done directly at the SQL level, and the database merely exposes an interface to that functionality via PDO.